# What is the best way to graph this in excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I have a table in excel with three columns:

```
Name  
Start Date  
End Date
```

I want to create a chart with count on the left hand side and date on the bottom to show the count of open item (defines as > start date and < end date) over time.  So for example, if my data looked like this

```
Name  Start   End  
===   ====    ====  
Dog   2010    2012  
Cat   2011    2012  
Mouse 2000    2008
```

That it would show a graph that would show 1 at year 2000 (as that was the first start date) and then go back to 0 in 2008 (as that ended) and then go to 1 in 2010 and then to 2 in 2011 and then to 0 in 2012.

Answer (score 2):

You have to set an intermediate table where you put your years and a countifs formula. Here is what it would be assuming your data is in Sheet1

```
       A      B
1    Year   Count
2    2000   =countifs(Sheet1!$B$2:B$4,">=" &A2,Sheet1!$C$2:C$4,"<=" &A2)
3    2001   copy down formula from above
4    etc.
```

Once that is set, graphing it will be easy.